# Convert numbers into comma separated format with two decimals in javascript

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I am trying to convert numbers into comma separated format with two decimal places for each and every number in javascript:

My code:

```
Number(parseFloat(n).toFixed(2)).toLocaleString('en');
```

This code doesn't show two decimal places (.00) for whole numbers.

I am expecting following results for a set of numbers:

```
10000 => 100,00.00
123233.12 => 123,233.12
300000.5  => 300,000.50
```

Appreciate your answer, thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the **`minimumFractionDigits`** option of the **`toLocaleString`** function.

```
// result 3,000.00
Number(parseFloat(3000).toFixed(2)).toLocaleString('en', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
});

// result 123,233.12
Number(parseFloat(123233.12).toFixed(2)).toLocaleString('en', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
});
```

You can even remove the parseFloat,toFixed and Number function usage as well, if this is not used for some  logic other than displaying the decimal value up to 2 digits.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution

Comment: Note that this only works for the locale 'en'. I tried to use another locale to replace the separator dot with a comma but that does not work, unfortunately.